# Handling Register Integer Value Wrap Around In x86 Assembly GNU on MacOSX

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, gnu, gnu-assembler

I am working with a simple example in x86 GNU GAS on MacOSX whereby an integer value of `300` is moved into the `eax` register. As expected, only `300 mod 256` (the value `44`), is actually stored in `%eax`, as `echo$?` reveals from Mac terminal:

```
.globl _main
_main:
   pushq %rbp
   movq %rsp, %rbp
   subq $16, %rsp
   movl $300, %eax;
   leave
   ret
```

However, I was under the impression that there is an overflow/wrap-around flag to denote that a wraparound occurred or a register storing the result of the integer division of `300` and `256`, the result being `1`. I have been unable to find any information detailing this process (if it exists) for x86 GNU. Does anyone know how the wraparound value or an overflow flag can be accessed?

Comment: Storing a value (using `mov`) doesn't set the flags. The value 300 can fit in EAX as EAX is a 32-bit register. When the value is returned from the process it is MOD 256 as only the lower 8 bits are returned to the shell.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Does that mean there is, in fact, a value of `300` still in the register `eax`, however, the `echo$?` process only returns the lower 8 bits? What about larger numbers, such as `10000`?

Comment: Correct EAX had the value 300 in it. A 32-bit register can hold an unsigned value between 0 to 4294967295 (2^32-1). If you use LLDB debugger to step through the code instruction by instruction you can query the EAX register and display its value.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of misconceptions in your question.

First, eax can hold values from 0 to 4294967295, so `mov $300, %eax` does in fact store 300 into eax.

Second, a mov instruction cannot overflow or wrap around; the size of the source and the size of the destination are the same. The overflow flag is used for arithmetic operations.

The reason `echo $?` prints 44 is that the operating system reports the low byte of the exit status of the process to the shell.

Comment: Thank you for your concise, detailed answer! +1 However, is there any way to print `300` in the shell, or is this not possible?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Well, you could make your program print out `300` instead of returning that as an exit status.  The exit status is not really meant for delivering large amounts of information.

Comment: @Ajax1234: The process exit status is packed into an `int` along with a field that says whether the process exited normally or received a signal, and if so what signal.  See [the OS X / BSD man page for `waitpid(2)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/waitpid/).  That's why the OS only keeps the low 8 bits of main's return value or the arg you pass to `_exit()`, so that's all that your shell can retrieve.  (Other Unix-like OSes are the same: exit status is an 8-bit integer.)